# Consuming a web service with WCF with just a public key

Tags: wcf, x509

I'm consuming a third-party's web service with WCF. I've got a PFX certificate file that I'm attaching via the `ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate` method. I'm using the "Message Security Version" `WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10`.

Everything works fine. Now the third-party's certificate is expiring so they've issued a new one. However, this time it's a P7B file with just the public key.

When I try to use this certificate, I get a `NotSupportedException` with the message "The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate."

No part of my code is supplying the private key password, so I'm assuming this means that the private key is not being used. If this is the case, how can I consume this web service using only the public key? Or have I misunderstood something? (very likely)

**EDIT**
Ok, here's some code. The service client class I'm using was generated by `svcutil` and has been modified via a partial class to implement `IDisposable`. These are the relevant fragments:

```
private ServiceResponse CallService(ServiceParameters serviceParameters)
{
    ...
    using (var client = new ThirdPartyServiceClient())
    {
        SetClientCredentials(client);
        client.RemoteCall(serviceParameters);
    }
    ...
}

private void SetClientCredentials(ThirdPartyServiceClient client)
{
    if (client.ClientCredentials == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("ClientCredentials was null and certificate could not be set");
    }

    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
        StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
        StoreName.My,
        X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
        _configuration.CertificateSubject);
}
```

And this is my WCF config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="ThirdPartyServiceBinding">
          <security includeTimestamp="true" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
          <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://third-party.com/service" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ThirdPartyServiceBinding" contract="Namespace.To.ProxyClasses" name="ThirdPartyService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The exception is thrown by the `client.RemoteCall(serviceParameters);` call, and the stack trace is

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey.GetSignatureFormatter(String algorithm)
   at System.IdentityModel.SignedXml.ComputeSignature(SecurityKey signingKey)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroSendSecurityHeader.CompletePrimarySignatureCore(SendSecurityHeaderElement[] signatureConfirmations, SecurityToken[] signedEndorsingTokens, SecurityToken[] signedTokens, SendSecurityHeaderElement[] basicTokens, Boolean isPrimarySignature)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroSendSecurityHeader.CreateSupportingSignature(SecurityToken token, SecurityKeyIdentifier identifier)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.SignWithSupportingToken(SecurityToken token, SecurityKeyIdentifierClause identifierClause)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.SignWithSupportingTokens()
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.CompleteSecurityApplication()
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAppliedMessage.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message, Boolean shouldRecycleBuffer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Namespace.To.ProxyClasses.ThirdPartyService.RemoteCall(ServiceParameters request)
   [back up the normal call hierarchy of my code]
```

Comment: Can you share the code that sets the certificate and detail exactly when the NotSupportedException gets thrown - including stack trace?

Comment: @RQDQ ok, here you go!

Answer (score 0):

With message security, you sign a document with your private key, and you encrypt a document with the other parties public key. They can decrypt it with their private key, and they can verify your signature with your public key. It sounds like they replaced their key so they provided you their new public key. If their public key doesn't have a publicly verifiable chain of trust, then you need to install their public key in your local certificate store as a trusted key. If you don't do this and they aren't publicly verifiable, you will get an exception about being unable to verify the chain trust. If it is your key which is expiring, then they need a public key to identify you, and you need the private half which they shouldn't have.